# Error message: NameError at /users/sign_in undefined local variable or method `require_no_authentication' for #<SessionsController:0x########>

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a RoR app with Devise. When I came in to work today and tried to start up my local dev environment, RoR failed when I tried to go to the sign in page:

```
NameError at /users/sign_in
undefined local variable or method `require_no_authentication' for #<SessionsController:0x########>
```

It looks like the error is not being raised within the code we wrote, but instead from deep within the Devise gem. I'm guessing that somehow, my dev machine isn't configured right.

Here are some things I've tried to fix the bug:

- I ran `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:terraform`.
- I ran `bundle install`.
- I ran `rvm gemset empty` and `bundle install` to reinstall all of my gems.

None of these worked.

In addition, here are a couple more strange things about this error:

- None of the other devs at my workplace are having the same error, even though they're on the same codebase.
- After trying to figure out the error for a while, I switched to a branch that I haven't updated since before I started getting this bug. Even though it was working before the weekend, that branch now fails with the same error.

Does anybody know anything I could do to try to fix this error? Does it sound like some part of my local configuration is incorrectly set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project, I had added a file in `app/controllers` called `devise_controller.rb`. It looked like this:

```
class DeviseController < ApplicationController
  # Asks Devise how much time is left until the current user is
  # automatically logged out, without resetting the logout timer.
  def time_until_logout
    raise "let's inspect here"
  end
end
```

When I deleted this file, the bug went away.

I filed a bug report about how adding a `DeviseController` caused RoR/Devise to blow up on Devise's repository: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2520

Comment: They closed the issue right away, leaving this message: "The problem is that once you define your own controller, Rails will stop loading the Devise one, that's why you can't use it.You need to define another controller or have a module and include into Devise inside a to_prepare hook, as shown here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts "